# objective C block to swift block

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am having trouble writing the method in objective C that calls a method in swift. I have all my headers set up correctly and simple methods are working but this I am not sure how to write the objective C side of this block.

**my swift class**

the function that i am trying to call:

```
func getOrders(completionHandler: (responseObject: NSString?) -> ()) {
    makeCall(completionHandler)
}
```

How I do it in swift (and what I want to do in Objective-C):

```
getOrders() { responseObject in
            // use responseObject and error here
            println("responseObject = \(responseObject); error = ")
            return
        }
```

and here is my attempt at **objective-C** block:

```
[billingService getOrders:completionHandler:^(NSString * responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"objective c callback: %@",responseObject);

}];
```

with the above I get use of undeclared identifier 'completionHandler'

I am just not sure how to make this work or construct a correct block in objective c.

Comment: so then please learn the basics of Objective-C (if you aren't even aware of the syntax of a simple method call). (consequently, this has nothing to do with blocks.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant In my question I state that simple method calls are working, by this I meant I have simple method calls from objective c working correctly, I just dont know how to do the block

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant If this is not a block what is it?

Comment: it's a block, but the fact that it's a block is irrelevant.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant So I know how to make a basic method call in objective c but I dont know how to make a block in objective c (which is what I am asking) yet this has nothing to do with blocks?

Comment: you apparently **don't** know how to call an Objective-C method because the code you just posted contains an obvious syntax error. (meanwhile, you did get the definition of the block right. so yeah, this has nothing to do with blocks.)

Comment: based on the default conversion, it is supposed to be something like: `[billingService getOrdersWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString * responseObject) { ... }];`... but Xcode can help you to autocomplete it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are not sure how to use Block in Objective C, take a look at this link:
http://fuckingblocksyntax.com/ (http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/ - SFW alternative)

To resume :
As a local variable:

```
returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes) = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
```

As a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);
```

As a method parameter:

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(returnType (^)(parameterTypes))blockName;
```

As an argument to a method call:

```
[someObject someMethodThatTakesABlock:^returnType (parameters) {...}];
```

As a typedef:

```
typedef returnType (^TypeName)(parameterTypes);
TypeName blockName = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
```

And this link if you need help to use block in swift :
https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/

Objective-c

```
- (void)hardProcessingWithString:(NSString *)input withCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *result))block;

    [object hardProcessingWithString:@“commands” withCompletion:^(NSString *result){
        NSLog(result);
    }];
}
```

Swift

```
func hardProcessingWithString(input: String, completion: (result: String) -> Void) {
    …
    completion(“we finished!”)
}

hardProcessingWithString(“commands”) {
    (result: String) in
    println(“got back: (result)“)
}
```

So for your issue, it might be :

```
[billingService getOrders: ^(NSString * responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"objective c callback: %@",responseObject);

}];
```

Hope it helps!